# From ByteArray (byte[]) To BufferedImage without ImageIO

Tags: java, lwjgl

In JDK 7 and LWJGL 2 for `BufferedImage` I used

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

This does not work for me in LWJGL 3 and JDK 8: 
No any error messages in the logs, no crashes. The program just freezes at the `ImageIO` lines

Can this (preferably) be replaced?

Comment: If you want people to help, you need to provide details. You say "this not worked for me ". How exactly is this the case? What errors or unexpected behaviour do you get?

Comment: thanx, a question has been updated

Comment: Which operating system are you using? On OS X AWT doesn't work together with LWJGL 3 too well.

Comment: +javac, thanx, yep, this is OS X. pity that so. i hope for a fixes and updates
but now a question - how get a BufferedImage to differently